# Scrapy cant scrape table, apears empty

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

Hi im trying to scrape some data from the table(id:datatable-1) in the following URL:
https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/scores_overall/sort_order/asc/cols/scores

I have this code in my spider:

```
import scrapy


class ScrapeTableSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scrape-table"
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/scores_overall/sort_order/asc/cols/scores']
    start_urls = ['https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2021/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/scores_overall/sort_order/asc/cols/scores']

    def start_requests(self):
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
        inspect_response(response, self)

        table = response.xpath('//*[@id="datatable-1"]//tbody')
        rows = table.xpath('//tr')
```

I use the shell so I can

```
view(response)
```

and as you can see the table is empty. Any clues on how i could get this done?
All help is appreciated.

first question, so sorry if something is wrong.

Comment: The table is loaded dynamically using JS, you will need a headless browser, consider using splash or selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `view(response)` it **should** direct you to the page you fetched.
If that command is returning empty, it means that your original fetch returns empty.

Taking a quick look in the scrapy shell, trying to fetch the URL you are using returns a code of 403.

A code 403 usually means you were denied access to the page.

Additionally, the table appears to be in javascript.
That means to scrape it you'll need a headless browser.
One of the most popular is [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/).